# Python socket are unreliable under windows

Tags: python, sockets, winsock

I am working on a cross platform project which listen to messages from a third-party app every 0.133 seconds.

On Linux, it works fine but on Windows after a few 1000 messages my socket starts to return `b''` and I have to re-connect to the server to be able to receive messages again, but by the time it is reconnected a few messages have been dropped and this is not acceptable for my project.

Have you ever encountered that kind of behavior ?
Is there a way to check what could be the issue ?
The big problem here is that the 'disconnect' (not even sure it is a disconnect) happens silently and I have no information to investigate the issue further.

I tried:

- tweaking socket [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ipproto-tcp-socket-options) but without success
- reconnect by reusing the old socket (`sock.connect()` but it raises the already connected exception)
- The socket internal buffer should be fine; it takes 0.05 seconds to process a single message, messages arrive every 0.133 seconds

In essence the code follows the structure below.

```py
import socket
from struct import unpack

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setblocking(True)
sock.connect((host, port))

while True:
    readable, _, error = select.select([sock], [], [sock], 0.250)
    
    for read in readable:
        # After a few 1000 messages this always returns b''
        # creating a new socket enable us to receive messages again
        # but a few messages were dropped in the meantime
        msg_size = read.recv(4)

        msg_len = int(unpack("@I", msg_size)[0])

        msg = read.recv(msg_len)
        assert len(msg) == msg_len
```

Thanks!

Comment: If `recv` returns an empty string that means that the connection has closed (see `pydoc socket.SocketType.recv`). That isn't "unreliable", that is the software telling you that something has happened to which you need to respond. That's an error condition your code needs to handle in any case, and it looks like you're ignoring it at the moment.

Comment: It is handled (not in the example but in the real code it is), but handling it drop messages. It never happens on linux which is a big issue. 

Why is the client only disconnecting on windows ?
Linux shows the disconnect was not necessary

Comment: *Linux shows the disconnect was not necessary"* - how does it show it? Note that all what is known here is the client code, the information that it returns `b''` (i.e. **orderly** TCP shutdown by the peer, not some error) and that this does not happen on Linux. There is nothing known about the environment, **nothing known** about the server, not known if this is really a difference between Windows vs. Linux or maybe instead the location of the client to the server (like same machine vs. different machine). It is **impossible to reproduce or debug the problem** just based on this information.

Comment: So you are saying the server side is closing the connection for an unknown reason for Windows clients  and I cannot debug the behaviour without the server log ?